# AWS CLI login with environment variables assuming a specific role

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cli

I am looking for a way to login to the AWS (and EKS) using the CLI using environment variables assuming a specific role.

Being able to assume the specific role is important as the role I have defined is mapped to my EKS cluster only allowing permissions in a single namespace. I am already able to login when defining `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.

I will be running this on a pipeline so using environment variables is required. The only way I got it to work currently is to set the env vars for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and inject them into the `~/.aws/credentials` file and creating a `~/.aws/config` file. I also have to `unset` the variables or use different variable names as the CLI attempts to use them which doesn't play well with the profile.

Example below:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*****REMOVED*****
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*****REMOVED*****

mkdir ~/.aws

cat <<EOT >> ~/.aws/config
[test]
region = us-east-1

[profile test-profile]
region = us-west-1
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/test-role
source_profile = test
EOT

cat <<EOT >> ~/.aws/credentials
[test]
aws_access_key_id = ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
aws_secret_access_key = ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
EOT
```

I don't mind going ahead with this approach but is not as clean as i'd like. Ideally all environment variables can be used for this.

Comment: I seems like you're looking for this:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html